# Polynomial solution to a multivariate system

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, rational-functions

Given two equations
$$mn=r\tag{1}$$
$$rn=b\tag{2}$$
where $m$, $r$, and $b$ are polynomials of multiple variables, is it generally possible to express $n$ as a polynomial of the same variables as the other functions? To be clear, I mean an $n$ that can be expressed as a ratio of polynomials, where the denominator of this ratio is constant.

Bivariate example:
If $r=xy$, $m=x$, and $b=y$, our equations become:
$$xn=xy$$
$$xyn=y$$
Considering the latter result first, we find that $n=1/x$ for $x \ne 0$, which does not satisfy our polynomial requirement. However, considering the first of these two equations, we find that $n=y$, which satisfies our requirements. This is an illustration of how the multivariate case differs from the univariate one.

My work so far:
Let's assume that the equation we use to define $n$ will be a linear combination of our $(1)$ and $(2)$ for fixed variables. Then this equation can be written as
$$n=\frac{k(r^2-bm)+bm}{mr}$$
where $k$ is a function. Here are some values of $n$ for several values of $k$, expressed as $(k,n)$: $(1,r/m),(0,b/r),((r^2+bm)/(bm),r^3/(bm^2))$

Comment: ??? In your example, $n=y$ satisfies the first equation but not the second.  When you write down a system of two equations, you generally mean both must be satisfied.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I see your point. With two equations, three unknowns, we can write our complete solution as $n=y,x=1/y,y=y$, or as $n=1/x,x=x,y=x$. My goal is to find solutions of the former type, where $n$ is a polynomial, rather than of the latter type. I know this is an unorthodox question, but I don't believe it's paradoxical. The specific problem I am trying to solve is two equations, >4 unknowns.

Comment: What are the unknowns, and what are the variables (i.e. indeterminates)?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, thank you for your responsiveness. In (1) and (2), $m$, $r$, and $b$ are known functions of some set of variables, while $n$ is an unknown function of these same variables. Is this clear?

Answer (score 0):

From the first equation, $n = r/m$ (unless $m=0$ as a polynomial).  This is a polynomial if and only if $m$ divides $r$.  You don't need the second equation unless $m=0$.

Comment: This is obviously true if $m$ and $r$ are polynomials of a single variable, but is it true in the case that $m$, $r$, and $b$ are polynomials of multiple variables?

Comment: @Arnold Why is it obvious for single variables ?

Comment: In my question I specified that $n$ is to be a polynomial _of the same variables as the other functions_. If all other functions used are polynomials of a single variable, say $x$, then $n = P(x)$. Then $P(x)$ can only be polynomial in the case that $r/m$ and $b/r$ are a) both polynomial and b) equal, if $n$ is to exist over all $x$.